# Sublime text find and replace with special characters

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I suck at regular expressions and what to do a simple find and replace of `'}'` to `'} /n'` notepad++ can recongise what I'm after as it has the 3 options of normal find and replace, special chars and full regex. I however only ever used to option two. How can I enable special characters in my search using sublime text 2.

Cheers

Comment: You did use `\n`, not `/n`, right? What happens when you do the replacement using option 1 or 2? There is no need for a regex here.

Comment: how can i do it on sublime text?

Answer (score 2):

Joe,

In sublime you can use find & replace. Drag the replace panel large enough and use cmd + enter to go to a new line.

[image]

Hit replace all:

[image]

And thats it your sorted chap

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace `}` within notepad++ with `} \n` you can use the following rules:

1. find: `}`
2. Replace with: `} \n`
3. Searchmethod: `Extended (\n, \e...)`
4. Press replace all